# Using four methods to count and display the lines, words, and characters in a file in java

Tags: java, file, methods

This is my first time using more than one method in a progam and I have also never tried to count lines, words and letters in a file. So I've read three Java books file sections and then looked at questions on the forum here and had a go. I think I am doing something wrong with variable names, as I don't know the rules with where you put them in in multi method etc. If you could say something like that is glaringly wrong because you have to do this, that would be helpful. I can't use the debugger because I can't compile it. Anyway, thanks for looking at this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

    /**
     * A program to count the number of lines, words and characters in a text file.
     * 
     * @author 
     * @version 2014
     */
    public class WordCount
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException 
        {
            // get the filename
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter the name of the file: ");
            String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

            lines(filename);
            words(filename);
            characters(filename);
        }

        /**
         * Count the number of lines in a file, and print out the result.
         * 
         */
        public static void lines(String filename)  throws FileNotFoundException 
        {
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
            int lines = 0;

            while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
            {
                lines++;
                file.nextLine();
            }
            return lines;

            inputFile.close();
        }

        /**
         * Count the number of words in a file, and print out the result.
         *
         */
        public static void words(String filename)  throws FileNotFoundException 
        {
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
            int words = 0;

            while (input.hasNextLine())
            {
                String word = input.next();
                words++;
            }
            return words;

            inputFile.close();
        }

        /**
         * Count the number of characters in a file, and print out the result.
         * 
         */
        public static void characters(String filename)  throws FileNotFoundException 
        {
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
            int characters = 0;

            while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = inputFile.nextLine();
                for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
                { characters = line.charAt(i);
                    if (character != 32) 
                    { 
                        characters++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return characters;
            inputFile.close();

            System.out.println("The number of lines is: " + lines);
            System.out.println("The number of words is: " + words);
            System.out.println("The number of characters is: " + characters);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You've read three Java books for tipps in file handling, but you haven't read the "how to work with methods" part? Why?If you can't compile your code, then add the error message to the question. And let me guess ... one error message in method `characters` is "unreachable code", right? Have you searched for that error message in one of your books or in the internet and tried to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains several problems. So let us fix that one by one in each method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    // get the filename
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the name of the file: ");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

    keyboard.close(); // <- don't forget to close this resource

    File file = new File(filename);
    //Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file); // <- this line is unnecessary, because you never use that variable

    lines(file); // <- you already obtained a File object, so use it ;)
    words(file);
    characters(file);
}
```

Next method:

```
public static void lines(File file)  throws FileNotFoundException // mind the new argument type
{
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    int lines = 0;

    while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        lines++;
        inputFile.nextLine(); //<- use "inputFile" instead of "file"
    }
    inputFile.close();
    //return lines; // <- you can't return something if your method uses "void" as the return type

    //your comment on that method says that you like to print the result, so let's do that
    System.out.println("The number of lines is: " + lines);
}
```

And the next one:

```
public static void words(File file)  throws FileNotFoundException // <- new argument type
{
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    int words = 0;

    while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        //String word = inputFile.next(); // that won't work like you think, but we can do a little "trick" here
        String line = inputFile.nextLine(); // read the current line of text
        words += line.split(" ").length; // split the line using whitespace and add the number of words to the current value of variable "words"

        //words++; // <- not needed anymore
    }
    //return words; // <- like before: not possible if return type is void

    inputFile.close();

    //your comment on that method says that you like to print the result, so let's do that
    System.out.println("The number of words is: " + words);
}
```

And the last method:

```
public static void characters(File file)  throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    int characters = 0;
    int count = 0; // new variable to count the characters

    while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
        {
            characters = line.charAt(i); // <- no harm in using a new line :)
            if (characters != 32) // <- you wrote "character"
            { 
                count++; // <- "characters" is the current character itself, we won't increase that. For example "a" would become "b" and we don't want/need that :)
            }
        }
    }
    //return characters; // <- you know that already ...
    inputFile.close();

    //System.out.println("The number of lines is: " + lines); // <- "lines" and "words" are unknown here, but we printed these results already
    //System.out.println("The number of words is: " + words);
    System.out.println("The number of characters is: " + count); // <- print the count of characters
    System.out.println();
}
```

After this changes you code should work now :).

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments and code. You laid it out very clearly and I now have a better grasp of what to do and not do.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following

```
public static int lines(String filename)  throws FileNotFoundException 
//change the return type to int instead of void
{
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(filename); //filename instead of file
    int lines = 0;

    while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        lines++;
        inputFile.nextLine(); // ---do----
    }
    inputFile.close(); // after return it will become unreachable
    return lines;
}
```

Same applies to other methods

Comment: Is there a reasing for removing the `inputFile.close()` line instead of switching this line with the return statement? Leaving the resource opened is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for that edit :). And btw. please don't think that I used the downvote to force you to change your answer. If you had a good reason for removing the `close` call I had also removed the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the methods only need the File object.

```
int n = countLines(file);
System.out.println("Lines: " + n);
...

public static int countLines(File textFile)  throws IOException 
{
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(textFile);
    int lines = 0
    while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        lines++;
        inputFile.nextLine();
    }
    inputFile.close();
    return lines;
}
```

For nextLine you asked the wrong object, Scanner needed.

`return` returns from the method, so close has come before.

As you return the line count, you must return int.

Method names contain a verb by convention.

The method knows no `file` or `filename`.
It also cannot alter a variable if you pass a variable, like `file`,
You can give the *new* paramaeter the same name, but for clarity not done here.

Answer (score 0):

Problem number 1:

```
public static void lines(String filename)  throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    int lines = 0;

    while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        lines++;
        file.nextLine();
    }
    return lines; // <----------------

    inputFile.close();
 }
```

This is a void method but you have a `return lines` statement. Either remove it or change the method header to `public static int lines(String filename)  throws FileNotFoundException`

Problem number 2

```
public static void words(String filename)  throws FileNotFoundException 
        {
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
            int words = 0;

            while (input.hasNextLine())
            {
                String word = input.next();
                words++;
            }
            return words; <-------------

            inputFile.close();
        }
```

Again here you ask from a void method to return a value. Change method header to `public static int words(String filename)  throws FileNotFoundException`

Problem number 3:

```
public static void characters(String filename)  throws FileNotFoundException 
        {
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
            int characters = 0;

            while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = inputFile.nextLine();
                for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
                { characters = line.charAt(i);
                    if (character != 32) 
                    { 
                        characters++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return characters; //<---------------
            inputFile.close();

            System.out.println("The number of lines is: " + lines);
            System.out.println("The number of words is: " + words);
            System.out.println("The number of characters is: " + characters);
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Again here you have a `return int` statement on a `void` method. Just change the method header to this: `public static int characters(String filename)  throws FileNotFoundException`